# Is the Format of cdimage.ubuntu.com Static?

Tags: system-installation, scripts, downloads, cd-image, zsync

Is the site layout of cdimage.ubuntu.com static? If I make a script to zsync an installation ISO every couple weeks will it be working a couple months/years from now?

If there are minor changes, do some sections stay static?

Comment: While the structure has been stable for many years, there is no promise that it will remain so.

Comment: Many things will change, EOL releases can disappear being moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com instead (though if a LTS reaches the end of it's supported life and enters ESM support, this move can be delayed until after ESM support ends).  Some things get stopped, eg. when x86 builds for 19.04 (flavors) were stopped they disappeared from the site as I recall the following week.  I suspect you'll need to be more specific.  Flavors tend to be removed earlier than main ubuntu.